# How can I make a dm-crypt folder world writeable?

Tags: linux, encrypting-file-system

I've set up an encrypted directory with dm-crypt. how can I make it world writeable (for my ftp server)?

Answer (score 0):

If the encrypted directory is mounted already, then find out what user your ftp daemon is running as, and then run `chgrp <group> /path/to/dir` and then `chmod g+w /path/to/dir`.

An alternative is to specify the `uid` or `gid` and permissions in the mount options, specified in /etc/fstab.